# Line features with equal parameters different visualisation

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have three different line features on a map all three with equal visualisation parameters (line width, line style, etc) but with one of them the dots/small lines that form the feature appear to be longer, so it seems to be a solid line when it is supposed to be a dotted line.

Some info that might be useful to solve this issue: every time I've had this problem with a file it's been created with the GPX segment importer tool and after I've saved them as a shapefile.

[image: 3 line features different visualisation]

Comment: Not sure why this issue is happening, but you can work around it by using a custom dash pattern with wider spaces for the one line that behaves differently.